# AMM0000 android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#com.microsoft.appcenter.push.TokenService>. Apps targeting Android 12

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have updated targetsdkversion from 30 to 31(andtio OS 12) facing the below issue.

`java.exe error AMM0000:  android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#com.microsoft.appcenter.push.TokenService>. Apps targeting Android 12`

In my application im using firebase push notification service and i added all the services for notification related. The below code im using in Andriodmanifest.xml

````
          android:installLocation="preferExternal"
          package="com.edmatix.parent.shemida"
          android:versionName="production.release.1.0.0.0"
          android:versionCode="20220818">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:label="SHEMIDA INTERNATIONAL SCHOOL" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"  android:icon="@drawable/SHEMIDA_Launcher" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAnvG581Y_oVWbDcwYNDy6v4CfRdtmU2CY" />
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <service android:name="com.microsoft.appcenter.push.TokenService" android:exported="true"/>
      <service android:name="crc646c47bac7b09c0b0e.MyFirebaseIIDService" android:exported="true"/>
        <service android:name="crc646c47bac7b09c0b0e.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true"/>
          <receiver android:name="crc64a93b901f58a35d0f.PushReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
            <service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseIIDService" android:exported="true"/>
              <service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true"/>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>```



Kindly help on this. im new to xamarin forms
````

Comment: where you able to fix this even i am facing this issue in one of my project can you please let me know the solution you applied to fix this

Answer (score 2):

These look like they are defined in code which are then auto-generated into the AndroidManifest upon building the solution.

```
<service android:name="crc646c47bac7b09c0b0e.MyFirebaseIIDService" android:exported="true"/>
<service android:name="crc646c47bac7b09c0b0e.MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true"/>
<receiver android:name="crc64a93b901f58a35d0f.PushReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
<service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseIIDService" android:exported="true"/>
<service android:name="crc6494e14b9856016c30.PNFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="true"/>
```

To fix them add the ***Exported*** flag to the attribute on the class itself, like so:

```
[Service(Exported = true)]
public class MyFirebaseIIDService: FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    public static string Token => FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
    public static event Action<string> TokenRefreshed;

    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        TokenRefreshed?.Invoke(Token);
    }
}
```